# Clear HTML Canvas and Re-Upload an Element in the Same Function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a web-based application which allows users to upload an image and then add logos and text.

Obviously, if they need to change the logo it will be necessary for them to clear the canvas and add the logo again. However, I can't work out how to clear the canvas and re-upload the background image they have already added, to save them from having to upload the background image for a second time too.

The code to upload the background image in the first place is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', doUpload);
function doUpload(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    if(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function loadBg(event){
            canvasLoadImage(event.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
function canvasLoadImage(imgData){  
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgData;
    img.onload = function drawBg(){
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, img.height * (1280/img.width));
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to clear the canvas is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
  }, false);
```

Does anyone know how I might re-add the image a user has already uploaded as part of the same function, and without them having to upload it for a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may save the data in a global variable and reuse it as a result of the cancellation of the canvas. For example:

```
var oData = null;
...
function canvasLoadImage(imgData){  
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = imgData;
                oData = imgData;
                img.onload = function drawBg(){
                    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                    var context = c.getContext("2d");
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, img.height * (1280/img.width));
                }
            }

...

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var context = c.getContext("2d");
                context.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);  
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = oData;
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, img.height * (1280/img.width));
              }, false);
```